can't handle traps with snmptrap
I'm trying to execute a script when trap arrives but I can't see script executes.
My snmptrapd.conf
#
# EXAMPLE-trap.conf:
#   An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP snmptrapd agent.
#
###############################################################################
#
# This file is intended to only be an example.
# When the snmptrapd agent starts up, this is where it will look for it.
#
# All lines beginning with a '#' are comments and are intended for you
# to read.  All other lines are configuration commands for the agent.

#
# PLEASE: read the snmptrapd.conf(5) manual page as well!
#
#authCommunity log,execute,net private　
#authCommunity log,execute,net public
#
## send mail when get any events
#traphandle default /usr/bin/traptoemail -s smtp.example.org foobar@example.org
#
## send mail when get linkDown
#traphandle .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 /usr/bin/traptoemail -s smtp.example.org foobar@example.org
authcommunity log,execute,net public
traphandle default /tmp/kk.sh

My snmp.conf
root@agente:/etc/snmp# more snmp.conf
# As the snmp packages come without MIB files due to license reasons, loading
# of MIBs is disabled by default. If you added the MIBs you can reenable
# loading them by commenting out the following line.
mibs : +ALL

My snmpd.conf
    ###############################################################################
#
# EXAMPLE.conf:
#   An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP agent ('snmpd')
#   See the 'snmpd.conf(5)' man page for details
#
#  Some entries are deliberately commented out, and will need to be explicitly activated
#
###############################################################################
#
#  AGENT BEHAVIOUR
#

#  Listen for connections from the local system only
#agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
agentaddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161




###############################################################################
#
#  SNMPv3 AUTHENTICATION
#
#  Note that these particular settings don't actually belong here.
#  They should be copied to the file /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf
#     and the passwords changed, before being uncommented in that file *only*.
#  Then restart the agent

#  createUser authOnlyUser  MD5 "remember to change this password"
#  createUser authPrivUser  SHA "remember to change this one too"  DES
#  createUser internalUser  MD5 "this is only ever used internally, but still change the password"

#  If you also change the usernames (which might be sensible),
#  then remember to update the other occurances in this example config file to match.



###############################################################################
#
#  ACCESS CONTROL
#

                                                 #  system + hrSystem groups only

view all .1

view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1

view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
#rocommunity public  localhost
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                                 #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
 rocommunity6 public  default   -V systemonly

                                                 #  Full access from an example network
                                                 #     Adjust this network address to match your local
                                                 #     settings, change the community string,
                                                 #     and check the 'agentAddress' setting above
#rocommunity secret  10.0.0.0/16

                                                 #  Full read-only access for SNMPv3
 rouser   authOnlyUser
                                                 #  Full write access for encrypted requests
                                                 #     Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
#rwuser   authPrivUser   priv

#  It's no longer typically necessary to use the full 'com2sec/group/access' configuration
#  r[ow]user and r[ow]community, together with suitable views, should cover most requirements



###############################################################################
#
#  SYSTEM INFORMATION
#

#  Note that setting these values here, results in the corresponding MIB objects being 'read-only'
#  See snmpd.conf(5) for more details
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>
                                                 # Application + End-to-End layers
sysServices    72


#
#  Process Monitoring
#
                               # At least one  'mountd' process
proc  mountd
                               # No more than 4 'ntalkd' processes - 0 is OK
proc  ntalkd    4
                               # At least one 'sendmail' process, but no more than 10
proc  sendmail 10 1

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::prTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "proc" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  Disk Monitoring
#
                               # 10MBs required on root disk, 5% free on /var, 10% free on all other disks
disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "disk" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  System Load
#
                               # Unacceptable 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages
load   12 10 5

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::laTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table *will* be populated, even without a "load" entry in the snmpd.conf file



###############################################################################
#
#  ACTIVE MONITORING
#

                                    #   send SNMPv1  traps
 trapsink     localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c traps
#trap2sink    localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c INFORMs
#informsink   localhost public

#  Note that you typically only want *one* of these three lines
#  Uncommenting two (or all three) will result in multiple copies of each notification.


#
#  Event MIB - automatically generate alerts
#
                                   # Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
iquerySecName   internalUser
rouser          internalUser
                                   # generate traps on UCD error conditions
defaultMonitors          yes
                                   # generate traps on linkUp/Down
linkUpDownNotifications  yes



###############################################################################
#
#  EXTENDING THE AGENT
#

#
#  Arbitrary extension commands
#
 extend    test1   /bin/echo  Hello, world!
 extend-sh test2   echo Hello, world! ; echo Hi there ; exit 35
#extend-sh test3   /bin/sh /tmp/shtest

#  Note that this last entry requires the script '/tmp/shtest' to be created first,
#    containing the same three shell commands, before the line is uncommented

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB tables (nsExtendConfigTable, nsExtendOutput1Table
#     and nsExtendOutput2Table) to see the resulting output

#  Note that the "extend" directive supercedes the previous "exec" and "sh" directives
#  However, walking the UCD-SNMP-MIB::extTable should still returns the same output,
#     as well as the fuller results in the above tables.


#
#  "Pass-through" MIB extension command
#
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /bin/sh       PREFIX/local/passtest
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /usr/bin/perl PREFIX/local/passtest.pl

# Note that this requires one of the two 'passtest' scripts to be installed first,
#    before the appropriate line is uncommented.
# These scripts can be found in the 'local' directory of the source distribution,
#     and are not installed automatically.

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB::netSnmpPassExamples subtree to see the resulting output


#
#  AgentX Sub-agents
#
                                           #  Run as an AgentX master agent
 master          agentx
                                           #  Listen for network connections (from localhost)
                                           #    rather than the default named socket /var/agentx/master
#agentXSocket    tcp:localhost:705
rocommunity public

In logs of snmpd. I see:
tail -f snmpd.log
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 149: Warning: Unknown token: defaultMonitors.
/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 151: Warning: Unknown token: linkUpDownNotifications.
Turning on AgentX master support.
NET-SNMP version 5.7.3
Connection from UDP: [192.168.1.119]:53344->[192.168.1.123]:161
Connection from UDP: [192.168.1.119]:44156->[192.168.1.123]:161
Connection from UDP: [192.168.1.119]:42764->[192.168.1.123]:161

Log of snmpdtrap:
root@agente:/var/log# tail -f snmptrapd.log
NET-SNMP version 5.7.3 AgentX subagent connected
NET-SNMP version 5.7.3

In syslog I can't see any error. Anyone can help me please?
Thanks

You only shared snmptrapd.conf. What's the command you use to send out TRAP messages? You should also enable snmptrapd logging, so see what happens after it receives the messages.

It's not a command. It's another server than send traps to ip where is snmpd and snmpdtrap. I typed the log of snmpd in main post

Try to generate a log file and turn on all log entries, https://serverfault.com/questions/1052006/linux-snmptrapd-how-to-write-to-a-custom-log-file-or-execute-a-custom-command That should tell you enough details on what's wrong. I still recommend you send test messages via snmptrap on this machine so as to learn if anything is wrong locally. After that you can move on to test with remote devices.

BTW, snmpd.log is from snmpd, not snmptrapd. They are different things.

I have service up redirecting output to logs snmpd.log and snmptrapd.log but don't say me nothing. I 've edited with the logs the main post

Ummm, it seems that If I execute these from another server it shows me something in the log: snmptrap -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.123 "" NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate i 123456 Shows me: 4-04-30 00:06:34  [UDP: [192.168.1.119]:41973->[192.168.1.123]:162]:
RFC1155-SMI::mgmt.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (1932420) 5:22:04.20     RFC1155-SMI::internet.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: RFC1155-SMI::enterprises.8072.2.3.0.1        RFC1155-SMI::enterprises.8072.2.3.2.1 = INTEGER: 123456. And executing the script!

OK. That's a good start, as it proves that you configured the agent properly. You can move on to troubleshoot the other scenarios, with the log, as well as tools like Wireshark.
